# ES6 pass an object to constructor and set property

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Look at the below example:

```
class Parent {
    constructor({ parentOnlyArg = 'default value' } = {}) {
        this.parentOnlyArg = parentOnlyArg;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    // this class and also any class inheriting from it
    constructor({ visibleStyle = 'inline' } = {}) {

        // I want to pass argument to super as an object
        super(/** args **/);

        this.visibleStyle = visibleStyle;
    }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
    // Specifying parentOnlyArg as default will change the behaviour
    constructor({ parentOnlyArg = 'another parent value',
                  someOther = 'value' } = {}) {

        // I want to pass argument to super as an object
        super(/** args **/);

        this.someOther = someOther;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to pass on the constructor argument to super?

**Seems like it was simpler than I thought**

```
super(...arguments);
```

I can then create `Child` using

```
var c1 = new Child(); // c.parentOnlyArg = 'default value'
var c2 = new Child2(); // c.parentOnlyArg = 'another parent value'
var c3 = new Child({ parentOnlyArg: 'changed again' }); // c.parentOnlyArg = 'changed again'
```

Comment: Why not post a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor?

Comment: `super({parentOnlyArg})`?

Comment: Any reason not to move the destructuring into the body of your function? Then you'll have a reference to the variable to pass through.

Comment: @loganfsmyth So you mean I should destruct before `super`? Like `let { parentOnlyArg='value', visibleStyle='inline'} = args` and then `super(args)`? I don't know if any of the object members are set. How would I handle that? `Object.assign` with default values?

Comment: @bergi I can do that however I want the class to only use the parameters it is interested in. In all cases a parameter will map to a class member or ignore it.

Comment: @Asken Yes, the destructuring does exactly that, use the properties that you declared as interesting. Not sure what the problem is with my solution, can you provide an example call maybe?

Comment: @bergi If I add a new property to parent I don't want to specify it for every super in "child-classes". I basically want to do what the only answer is suggesting. Maybe that's the only way?

Comment: @Asken If you change the interface of the parent - i.e. the constructor taking one more parameter - you should indeed need to change everything that inherits this, just like you need to change every place where it is called. Especially when the child constructor has its own defaults for the parent constructor arguments (`'value'`).

Comment: @bergi I want to set parameters based on config instead of function parameters. As simple as that.

Comment: @mplungjan I've updated the example but actually after figuring out how to get it done. I can't see how to start the snippet editor. Is it too late for that now?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [object destructuring with rest properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread). It is not yet implemented by browsers, but [BabelJs](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=react%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoFEC2ADlAJ4AUcARgFYCUiA3gFCKIzCJkDyNG0AdAGsMJVBRq1-AGwxgA5lAAWiAHyIADPWatWSrHADuiMBiO4s-rGQBEAVRMAPQnygYAJokLIsyfBldYqNa0ANwsiAC-TFFMEFJoqIgAgozhEAioUFgg0HBWDMgAvNbAcHDWADSI_DVYGJkRhQwRWuGsCdh4RKRkdZmhbYjpYKhwMtJwcjYmRinWiADUKAOsUTFxCYgAQogYDq5gbokp2kMZWTlQeWQMlMWU3pXVtfVQjc2tOoioIM5WfVAVjphqNxlJJtNTNtEPMlpQgWsmEiZtsbsgAFwAJhaYRRWzR6IALFVKOiAKxVCDogBsOKRQA&playground=true) can transpile it.

```js
function assertEmpty(obj) {
  if (Object.keys(obj).length > 0) {
    throw new Error("Unexpected parameters");
  }
}
    
class A {
  constructor({ a = "foo", ...rest } = {}) {
    assertEmpty(rest);
    console.log("new A " + a);
  }
}
    
class B extends A {
  constructor({ b = "bar", ...rest } = {}) {
    super(rest);
    console.log("new B " + b);
  }
}
    
new B({a:2}); // prints 'new A 2', 'new B bar'
new B({a:4, b:5, c:6}); // throws 'Unexpected parameters'
```

In the above snippet parent classes don't see the params consumed by the descendants. If you have problems with that you can do it either as @Bergi or @loganfsmyth suggested. For example:

```js
class A {
  constructor(params = {}) {
    const { a = "foo" } = params;
    console.log("a=" + a);
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(params = {}) {
    const { b = "bar" } = params;
    super(params);
    console.log("b=" + b);
  }
}

new B({a:2}); // prints a=2 b=bar
new B({b:5}); // prints a=foo b=5
```

Comment: In my update where I just pass `...arguments` to `super` it also seems to work and I pass all arguments to parent and also keep default values. Do you see any problems with that solution?

Comment: The only problem might be performance related, they say modern browsers cannot optimize functions which access the arguments object well. But it is fine otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A quick-win is to use the `arguments` object. It is an array containing all parameters passed to a function.

More information on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Fonctions/arguments).

In practice, you can access to the first parameter of your function thanks to `arguments[0]`.

```
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor({ parentOnlyArg = 'value',
                  visibleStyle = 'inline' } = {}) {
        super(arguments[0]);
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is not wrong this is how I would do it a week ago. Lacking other options this will be the answer.